# Visual Studio: SSH refuses to connect

Tags: visual-studio

If you go into Options > Cross Platform, where's an option to set up an SSH connection. However, I *cannot* force this thing to connect.

I have a Linux machine, I can connect to it with PuTTY just fine using password authentication. However, when I try to configure a connection in Visual Studio, it highlights the username and password boxes in red, as if there's a problem with them. I have *no idea* why it's not letting me log in. No matter which account I try, it just refuses. There's no diagnostic message or anything, it just highlights the fields in red.

Is there some prerequisit I'm missing? I don't understand why it won't let me connect. Is there somewhere I can look for extra diagnostic output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so it took me quite some time to figure this out. I'm writing this in case it helps anyone else...

- Options > Cross Platform > Connection Manager is the page I was looking at, where you can set up an SSH connection. However, if you go to Options > Cross Platform > Logging and Diagnostics, you can click a button to turn on diagnostic logging. (!)
- Once logging was turned on, VS reports:

  ```
  Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
  ```

In other words, VS isn't even *trying* to authenticate, because none of the available methods on the SSH server match the methods VS is trying to use.

- Long story short, it turns out password authentication is *disabled* on the SSH server. "What?! But I use password authentication *every day* to log in!" No, you do not. Apparently there is "password" authentication and "keyboard interactive" authentication, and these are somehow not the same thing. You log in using "keyboard interactive" auth, *which is enabled*, but VS is trying to use "password" auth, *which is disabled*. Once you realise this, it's perfectly obvious why you can't log in.

So, go edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and turn on password authentication. (In my case, there was a line that literally says `PasswordAuthentication no`. Change that to `yes`, restart the SSH daemon, VS can now connect just fine.)